# How to change url for magnolia cms application

Tags: magnolia

I would like to ask about the way how I shoudl change my app link when moving to production.
During dev it was like //mydomain.com/magnoliaPublic/myApp/  but now I have to change it to be like myclientdomain.com/  without magnoliaPublic/myApp.    Inside the jsp pages I have links for images pointing to the one with magnoliaPublic/resource/myApp.

Best Regards
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically three possibilities:

1. Use Apache with mod_rewrite: https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Rewrite+URLs+with+Apache
2. Define two independent `Service`s in your Tomcat's server.xml (e.g. `author.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`), and deploy author instance in the first one, and public instance in the second one, both as a `ROOT` webapp. Then use Apache and mod_proxy.
3. If you cannot use Apache HTTPD to proxy your Tomcat, you can still deploy the public instance as `ROOT` webapp, and keep the author instance as `magnoliaAuthor` (or just `author`). Then you will have your public instance as `mydomain.com` and author instance as `mydomain.com/author` (of course if you configure your Tomcat to run at the port 80).

Comment: Dear @Jozef Chocholacek Sorry for asking here. But maybe you could help me with following problem ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548423/magnolia-cms-imaging-module-together-with-resource-module

Comment: @johnnyGor Regrettably, I don't know imaging module too much. I'd suggest to ask directly on Magnolia CMS forum.

Comment: We have changed and are using proxy mode right now. But when I make redirect return "redirect:/" the url is changing to something like http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/  instead of the one with correct domain. It seems that all redirects go to localhost taken from apache redirect. It is also impossible to change the request from http to https. Do you have any idea how I can solve this ?  As I know administrator set the ProxyPreserveHost off flag in his configuration.
Best ragards Jan

Comment: @johnnyGor check the value of the `/server/defaultBaseUrl` property in your public instance

Comment: It's http://localhost:8080/magnolia   but in redirect I'm getting like http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/

Comment: can I cantact to you on priv, please ?

Comment: `[firstName].[lastName]@gmail.com`